# R package ggpmisc: Putting hat on y in Regression Equation

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

I'm using `R` package `ggpmisc`. Wonder how to put hat on y in Regression Equation or how to get custom Response and Explanatory variable name in Regression Equation on graph.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

df <- data.frame(x1 = c(1:100))
set.seed(12345)
df$y1 <- 2 + 3 * df$x1 + rnorm(100, sd = 40)

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x1, y = y1)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               parse = TRUE) +         
  geom_point()
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would turn off the default value for `y` that is pasted in and build your own formula. For example

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x1, y = y1)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, eq.with.lhs=FALSE,
      aes(label = paste("hat(italic(y))","~`=`~",..eq.label..,"~~~", ..rr.label.., sep = "")), 
      parse = TRUE) +         
  geom_point()
```

We use `eq.with.lhs=FALSE` to turn off the automatic inclusion of `y=` and then we `paste()` the `hat(y)` on to the front (with the equals sign). Note that the formatting comes from the `?plotmath` help page.

[image]

Comment: Excellent @MrFlick. Thanks for very helpful answer. Would highly appreciate if you guide how to change the name of explanatory variable. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the desired output?

Comment: How to change the name of explanatory variable x in regression equation, say Income in place of x in the regression equation.

Comment: You can replace `..eq.label..` with  `gsub("x","Income",..eq.label..)` or `gsub("italic(x)","Income",..eq.label..,fixed=T)`